# Why pytorch(CUDA) couldn't allocate 290MB when there are 5GB of memory free

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu

Solution: I solved this problem by uninstalling the Nvidia GPU driver then reinstalling it. Running the driver installer without uninstalling it doesn’t work.

——————————————————————-

The Original Problem:

I got this error when I'm training a large CNN model.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dkdk\miniconda3\envs\transfer\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dkdk\miniconda3\envs\transfer\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\batchnorm.py", line 107, in forward
    exponential_average_factor, self.eps)
  File "C:\Users\dkdk\miniconda3\envs\transfer\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1670, in batch_norm
    training, momentum, eps, torch.backends.cudnn.enabled
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 290.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 673.67 MiB already allocated; 5.27 GiB free; 686.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

You can see from the error message there are obviously 5.27GB of memory free in my GPU, but pytorch is only reserving 686MB. It used to have more than 5GB memory reserved. I tried another project running with Keras, Keras runs the project fine and allocated 5GB of memory.

I'm using GeForce RTX2080, Pytorch 1.4, CUDA Toolkit v10.1 on Windows

I thought this might be a driver issue. I reinstalled the Nvidia driver, which doesn't fix anything. I also tried downgrade to toolkit v9.2 and doesn't work as well. So I wonder what would cause this to happen and how should I fix this?

Output from running nvidia-smi when process is not running:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 442.19       Driver Version: 442.19       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2080   WDDM  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 32%   29C    P8     1W / 225W |    911MiB /  8192MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       908    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe    N/A      |
|    0      6524    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0     13760    C+G   ...DIA GeForce Experience\NVIDIA Share.exe N/A      |
|    0     14892    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe    N/A      |
|    0     16452    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe    N/A      |
|    0     24656    C+G   C:\Program Files\NZXT CAM\NZXT CAM.exe     N/A      |
|    0     26168    C+G   ...t_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0     31108    C+G   ...AppData\Local\slack\app-4.4.0\slack.exe N/A      |
|    0     36420    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe    N/A      |
|    0     37340    C+G   ...oftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe N/A      |
|    0     37428    C+G   ...dows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe N/A      |
|    0     37440    C+G   ...osoft.LockApp_cw5n1h2txyewy\LockApp.exe N/A      |
|    0     37588    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe    N/A      |
|    0     38396    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0     40804    C+G   ...hell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp.exe N/A      |
|    0     41584    C+G   ...6)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe N/A      |
|    0     44740    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

outputs from running nvidia-smi when the process is running:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 442.19       Driver Version: 442.19       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2080   WDDM  | 00000000:02:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 32%   31C    P8     1W / 225W |   1291MiB /  8192MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       908    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe    N/A      |
|    0      6524    C+G   ...5n1h2txyewy\StartMenuExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0     13284      C   ...miniconda3\envs\transfer\python.exe     N/A      |
|    0     13760    C+G   ...DIA GeForce Experience\NVIDIA Share.exe N/A      |
|    0     14892    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe    N/A      |
|    0     16452    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe    N/A      |
|    0     24656    C+G   C:\Program Files\NZXT CAM\NZXT CAM.exe     N/A      |
|    0     26168    C+G   ...t_cw5n1h2txyewy\ShellExperienceHost.exe N/A      |
|    0     31108    C+G   ...AppData\Local\slack\app-4.4.0\slack.exe N/A      |
|    0     36420    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe    N/A      |
|    0     37340    C+G   ...oftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe\MicrosoftEdge.exe N/A      |
|    0     37428    C+G   ...dows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy\SearchUI.exe N/A      |
|    0     37440    C+G   ...osoft.LockApp_cw5n1h2txyewy\LockApp.exe N/A      |
|    0     37588    C+G   C:\Windows\System32\MicrosoftEdgeCP.exe    N/A      |
|    0     38396    C+G   Insufficient Permissions                   N/A      |
|    0     40804    C+G   ...hell.Experiences.TextInput.InputApp.exe N/A      |
|    0     41584    C+G   ...6)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe N/A      |
|    0     44740    C+G   C:\Windows\explorer.exe                    N/A      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Besides the error above, sometimes the error becomes "CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/research/docs/transfer/train.py", line 32, in <module>
    lrn.train()
  File "E:\research\docs\transfer\main.py", line 592, in train
    outputs = self.model(train_inputs.float())
  File "C:\Users\dkdk\miniconda3\envs\transfer\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "E:\research\docs\transfer\builder.py", line 679, in forward
    x = self.bn_list[i](F.relu(self.conv_list[i](x)))
  File "C:\Users\dkdk\miniconda3\envs\histotransfer\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\dkdk\miniconda3\envs\histotransfer\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 345, in forward
    return self.conv2d_forward(input, self.weight)
  File "C:\Users\dkdk\miniconda3\envs\histotransfer\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 342, in conv2d_forward
    self.padding, self.dilation, self.groups)
RuntimeError: cuDNN error: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
```

Comment: Hi. Maybe there is something wrong the error message. Have you tried running `nvidia-smi` from terminal? I would like to see the output of that (I am assuming you are using ubuntu)

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I add my nvidia-smi output to the question, and another update: I restarted my computer again. Keras seems to be working now and allocated 5GB memory, but pytorch is still not allocating memory properly. Same error occurs, and as I kept on re-starting the training process, the memory it allocated become less and less (from 3GB originally to 106MB now)

Comment: There may be something else wrong in your code. So, posting your code may help. Also, try reducing the batch size and see if it works.

Comment: I think it´s because when processing it uses more than available. And when it is full and tries to perform a new operation it fails. You should check nvidia-smi when processing. What are your inputs? Images? What's your batch size??

Comment: @ShalonIsaac My inputs are images and my batch size is 32 --- I tried reducing it to 8 and still doesn't work. I included my nvidia-smi in the question. I don't think this is using the full memory because now the program couldn't even load the the images into the dataset.  A few hours earlier, it can still run a few batches.